# Order table column in asc/desc order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple table that sorts a column in ascending/descending order when you click a column. However, I want each column to "remember" it's previous state, and do the opposite when it is clicked. For example, if I click on the column name `name` for the first time it will be sorted asc. Then assume I click on a different column and it is sorted by that asc. Then I click `name` again. `name` should be sorted in descending order.

However, the method that I am using doesn't store *which* column, and even if I did, I would be unable to access it in the sorting part of the code. I use `ng-repeat` on the row not on the columns, so i'm unsure how to proceed. The arrows work properly, (except you should only be sorting 1 at a time, so only 1 should be visible), but how would I access the column name in the row repeat section? Any ideas?

Here is a [JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/josueespinosa/gcWLm/3/)

Code:

```
        <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.data = tastyJSON;

        $scope.columns = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);

        $scope.order = {};

        $scope.sort = function(column){
            console.log(angular.toJson($scope.order));
        if ($scope.order[column] == column) {
            $scope.order[column+'Desc'] = !$scope.order[column+'Desc'];
        } else {
            $scope.order[column] = column;
            $scope.order[column+'Desc'] = false;
        }
        };

    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-click="sort(column)">
                <a href="">{{column}}</a>
                <a ng-show="order[column] == column && order[column+'Desc']">v</a>
                <a ng-show="order[column] == column && !order[column+'Desc']">^</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data | orderBy:order[column]: order[column+'Desc']">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
                {{row[column]}} 

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close! The only thing you're missing is keeping track of the current sort. Here are my changes:

```
$scope.sort = function(column){
  if ($scope.order[column] == column) {
    $scope.order[column+'Desc'] = !$scope.order[column+'Desc'];
  } else {
    $scope.order[column] = column;
    $scope.order[column+'Desc'] = false;
  }

  $scope.currentSort = {exp: $scope.order[column], reverse: $scope.order[column+'Desc']} ;
};
```

View code:

```
<a ng-show="currentSort.exp == column && currentSort.reverse">v</a>
<a ng-show="currentSort.exp == column && !currentSort.reverse">^</a>
```

...

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data | orderBy:currentSort.exp: currentSort.reverse">
```

[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GnrsL/)

Comment: Should've known! It was so simple. Thanks.